# Results Dependent on Values in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationServers]
(
   [ServerName] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
   [ApplicationName] [nchar](10) NULL
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Alerts]
(
   [ServerName] [nchar](10) NULL,
   [AlertDescrption] [nchar](10) NULL,
   [AlertStatus] [int] NULL
)
GO
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT [dbo].[ApplicationServers] ([ServerName], [ApplicationName]) 
VALUES (N'Server1   ', N'App1      ')
INSERT [dbo].[ApplicationServers] ([ServerName], [ApplicationName]) 
VALUES (N'Server2   ', N'App1      ')
INSERT [dbo].[ApplicationServers] ([ServerName], [ApplicationName]) 
VALUES (N'Server3   ', N'App1      ')
INSERT [dbo].[ApplicationServers] ([ServerName], [ApplicationName]) 
VALUES (N'Server4   ', N'App2      ')
INSERT [dbo].[ApplicationServers] ([ServerName], [ApplicationName]) 
VALUES (N'Server5   ', N'App2      ')
INSERT [dbo].[Alerts] ([ServerName], [AlertDescrption], [AlertStatus]) 
VALUES (N'Server1   ', NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Alerts] ([ServerName], [AlertDescrption], [AlertStatus]) 
VALUES (N'Server3   ', NULL, 2)
```

I'm trying to form a query that would show 3 columns.

```
Server Name | Application Name | Server Status
```

Server Status would be calculated by joining on the Alerts table and if that particular ServerName has records in there with only a 1, then it would return "Warning", but if it has records in there with a "2" then it would show "Error". If there are no records at all for that ServerName, it would return "Normal".

Could someone help with that?

Comment: Can a server have more than one status?

Comment: No it can't, only "Warning", "Error" or "Normal". But there could be "Warning" records and "Error" warnings in the Alerts table so it would need to disregard the "Warning" ones and show "Error".

Comment: Then you might want to consider a re-design. I would expect `Alerts` to be just a reference table, with columns like `AlertID` and `Description`, and `ApplicationServers` to refer to that table via a reference column (probably called `AlertID` too, for consistency).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  CASE ax.Highest
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Error'
  WHEN 1 THEN 'Warning'
  ELSE 'Normal' END
FROM ApplicationServers a
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT MAX(AlertStatus) AS Highest
  FROM Alerts b
  WHERE a.ServerName = b.ServerName
) ax
```

OUTER APPLY involves two tables A and B and is helpful for doing requests on table B for each row of table A. We look for the highest value of any alert. Depending of that value, the status is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by using LEFT OUTER JOIN.

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7942/11)

```
SELECT   aps.ServerName,
         aps.ApplicationName,
         CASE 
              WHEN a.AlertStatus = 1 THEN 'Warning'
              WHEN a.AlertStatus = 2 THEN 'Error'
              ELSE 'Normal'
         END AS AlertStatus
FROM     ApplicationServers aps
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Alerts a
    ON   a.ServerName = aps.ServerName
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems like a basic join/aggregation query would be fine:

```
SELECT aps.ServerName, aps.ApplicationName,
       (CASE WHEN MAX(a.AlertStatus) = 2 THEN 'Error'
             WHEN MAX(a.AlertStatus) = 1 THEN 'Warning'
             ELSE 'Normal'
        END) as ServerStatus
FROM ApplicationServers aps LEFT JOIN
     Alerts a
     ON aps.ServerName = a.ServerName
GROUP BY aps.ServerName, aps.ApplicationName;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0d6dd/1) is a SQL Fiddle.